# Sybase 15.7 "select for update" + "readpast" race condition

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a simple SQL,

```
begin tran xxx;
select top 50 * from aTable readpast for update;
delete these "top 50" records;
commit tran xxx;
```

And I ran from three threads (each thread starts own transaction). What I have observed is that **sometimes** two threads are returning the same set of records.

According to Sybase manual, "for update" should have locked the records that I have selected and readpast should have prevented me from reading locked records.

isolation level is 1.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Is the server config `select for update` disabled (=0; default) or enabled (=1)?  If disabled (=0) then the `select`(read) will obtain a shared lock (an exclusive lock will only be obtained once the row is updated); to apply an exclusive lock during the `select` (read) the server config `select for update` should be set to `1`

Comment: @markp Yes, "Config Value" and "Run Value" are both set to 1

Comment: What's locking scheme is the table using?  allpages? datapages? datarows?
  according to the documentation for [select for update](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/BABHGBBB.htm), the table must be using the `datarows` locking scheme for the `select for update` to obtain an exclusive row lock during the select/read phase

Comment: @markp absolutely, datarows is the locking scheme. This problem is tricky because that it happens **sometimes** but not always. And so far what I have observed is that the bigger the "top" size, the more likely to happen.

Comment: If the issue is intermittent then I'd recommend opening a case with SAP tech support; they should be able to tell you if there's a known issue with your version of ASE or determine if this is a new issue